# Does anyone know where are the Qt dlls and how to link against them?

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2022, licensing, qt6

I am using Windows 11, Visual Studio 2022 and C++. I want to link Qt dynamically using the appropriate header files and dlls. This is where my Qt Open Source is installed: "D:\Qt\6.5.0"

I assume that the appropriate header files are the ones under "D:\Qt\6.5.0\msvc2019_64\include" but I am not sure. I noticed that there are some dlls under "D:\Qt\6.5.0\msvc2019_64\bin" but the compilation fails if attempting to link against those.

Other sources suggest building the dlls from source but I do not know how to do that. It should not be this hard. I was expecting to be able to download the dlls and link it just like GLFW.

I know I can link to the .lib files, but I want to comply with the license. The program I am writing is not to be open source.

Comment: `.lib`s in question are not static libs, but mere "import libs".

Comment: Can I then link to the ```.lib``` files as long as I do it dynamically? I've never done that. The website here https://www.qt.io/download-open-source#vc says to "Provide a re-linking mechanism for Qt libraries"

Comment: *I want to link Qt dynamically using the appropriate header files and dlls.* -- Your question starts off with the wrong assumptions.  A DLL is not used in the building of an application -- the DLL's don't even have to exist for the application to be built successfully.  DLL's are used at *runtime*, they are not part of the build process.  If you were to build your application successfully, on startup of your application, that is the time when the DLL's come into play -- the OS will either find those DLL's, or it won't find them (giving an error that the DLL's could not be found).

Comment: I am aware my vocabulary could have been more precise. Does anyone know how to link to Qt dll?

Comment: *Does anyone know how to link to Qt dll* -- It is impossible, because you don't link to DLL's.  That was the whole point of the comment I made.  You were given `.lib` files.  Are those files static libraries, or import libraries?  If they are import libraries, then these are nothing but stubs that tells the linker, "hey linker, there are some functions being called in my application, and I promise that at runtime, they exist in an external component somewhere on my system (the DLL)".  The linker believes you, and goes ahead and builds your app, but you can lie and not have those DLLs exist.

Comment: I suggest you build your application, and just run it.  Then see what DLL's are being loaded when your application starts.  If those DLL's are ones that violates the license agreement, then you need to work that out somehow.  I don't use Qt, but what Qt does in terms of DLLs and libraries is no different than any application that has external DLLs and provides import libraries for the build process.

Comment: I think @Osyotr might have been onto something. I have no idea the difference between a static library and mere import libraries because apparently they both have the same file extension. I set it up like I would with a static library, it linked and compiled, but when it ran, it asked for a ```qt6core.dll``` in a pup up window. I will continue to see if I can generate a simple UI now from my VS project. Hopefully @Osyotr is right. That dll was under the bin directory and I pasted it there and now runs a simple hello world program.

Comment: *I have no idea the difference between a static library and mere import libraries* -- Import libraries are relatively much smaller in size than static libraries.  If your library is multiple megabytes or close to it, it is more than likely a static library.

Comment: Yes, you are just as right as @Osyotr. So far everything is working fin. I've had a lot of big bumps along the road trying to make this work. Apparently you also need to include a folder named "platforms" and put some extra dlls that come with the Qt program under "Qt\6.5.0\msvc2019_64\plugins\platforms". Just putting that out there for future readers. I can at least display a window now.

Comment: Usually the platform files are located in the installation in a way that allows qt to find them. This assumes of course that the dlls are still where they were installed on your system. For your app to find them, you'll need to add Qt's bin dir to the `PATH` environment variable. You can do so without editing the system-wide values by setting `Configuration Properties > Debugging > Environment` to `PATH=D:\Qt\6.5.0\msvc2019_64\bin;$(PATH)` in the project properties of the executable target linking Qt...